# Angular: Combining interval with increment & decrementss

Tags: angular

I have a random number between 1 and 20 at intervals.
I need to add buttons to move up and down. (increment & decrement).
**I could not combine the intervals I have with my functions**

my stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zbrapb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css

The function that does a random number between 1 and 20:

```
  floor!: Observable<Number>;
  floorNumber = -1;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.floor = this.getNumbersInfinite();
  }

  getNumbersInfinite() {
    return interval(1000)
    .pipe(
      map(() => Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1),
      tap(res =>this.floorNumber=res));
  }
```

Unsuccessful implement of up and down:

```
 up(){
    if (Number(this.floorNumber) < 20 && Number(this.floorNumber) >= 1) {
       return Number(this.floorNumber++);
    }
    return false;
  }
  down(){
    if (Number(this.floorNumber) < 20 && Number(this.floorNumber) >= 1) {
       return Number(this.floorNumber--);
    }
    return false;
  }
```

html:

```
<p>
  {{ floor | async }}
</p>

<input type="button" value="Up" (click)="up()" />
<input type="button" value="down" (click)="down()" />
```

Comment: What are those up/down buttons suppose to do?

Comment: @Antoniossss for example: the random number is 10
So if I press **up** it will be 11

Comment: @Antoniossss You also need to set a range. If it's between 1 and 20 we can use up and down otherwise if I get to 20 and press up then it stays on 20 and the same goes for down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  floor = new ReplaySubject<number>(1);

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getNumbersInfinite();
  }

  getNumbersInfinite() {
    return interval(1000)
      .pipe(map(() => Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1))
      .subscribe(this.floor);
  }

  up() {
    this.floor
      .pipe(
        take(1),
        filter((v) => v < 20),
        map((v) => v + 1)
      )
      .subscribe((v) => this.floor.next(v));
  }

  down() {
    this.floor
      .pipe(
        take(1),
        filter((v) => v > 1),
        map((v) => v - 1)
      )
      .subscribe((v) => this.floor.next(v));
  }
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dxu7xx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css

Comment: Thanks for the help
But for some reason it does not make me the **next** property
any
Property 'next' does not exist on type 'Observable<number>'.ts(2339)

Comment: No idea what you mean, works fine in stackblitz

Comment: I succeeded, but I try to transfer the functions to the service and then call the functions through the ctor it does not work for me

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`merge()`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/merge) function to merge the three actions into one observable. Everytime an event happens from one of the observables the value will get sent to the template.

[See a working example here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-interval-click?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).

The new template is pretty much the same, we just now remove the click event and create it within the TypeScript using [`fromEvent()`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/fromEvent).

```html
<p>
  {{ output$ | async }}
</p>

<input type="button" value="Up" #up />
<input type="button" value="down" #down />
```

The TypeScript will:

- Create the up event
- Create the down event
- Create the interval
- listen to all three and emit a single observable

```js
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  // The current value
  current = 1;

  // Create an Observable from the click event of the up button
  up$!: Observable<number>;
  @ViewChild('up')
  set up(val: ElementRef<HTMLButtonElement>) {
    this.up$ = fromEvent(val.nativeElement, 'click').pipe(
      filter(() => this.current < 20),
      map(() => ++this.current)
    );
  }

  // Create an Observable from the click event of the down button
  down$!: Observable<number>;
  @ViewChild('down')
  set down(val: ElementRef<HTMLButtonElement>) {
    this.down$ = fromEvent(val.nativeElement, 'click').pipe(
      filter(() => this.current > 0),
      map(() => --this.current)
    );
  }

  // Create a timer observable that fires every "x" milliseconds
  interval$ = () =>
    timer(0, 1000).pipe(
      map(() => Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1),
      tap((i) => (this.current = i))
    );

  output$?: Observable<number>;

  // We need to merge here so the buttons are ready.
  // Merging sooner will cause an `undefined` error for the buttons
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // Merge the three observables and send the results to the template
    this.output$ = merge(this.up$, this.down$, this.interval$());
  }
}
```

Comment: You disable up/down when you are on the edges.

Comment: disable interval (or dont, but then click fast!), increment to 20, try to decrement